# Filenames and regular expressions

Tags: jquery, html, regex, filenames, image

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
<img src="*some regular expression here*">
```

I have a folder with a bunch of pictures and I'm trying to display all the pictures that fit the given regular expression.  Also, I'm using JQuery for this, so could is it possible to do something like:

```
<img src="*some regular expression searching for $(var1) and $(var2) within the filenames*">
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `img` tag in HTML can only load one image at a time. So you will need to create multiple images, and figure out what relation they have to each other. So you could do something like this:

```
var $parent = $('#parent_container');
$.each(filenames, function(i, filename) {
   if (filename.match(/my_patter(n*)/) {
        $parent.append('<img src="' + RegExp.$1 + '" />');
   }
});
```

Obviously your real filenames won't consist of the letter n repeated variable numbers of times.

This will place the images one after another in a single parent container.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.  One quick question though.  For the $.each(filenames, function(i,filename) part, how does it know how many files there are? I have all the files in foler/*images*.  How do I tell Jquery to iterate through all the images in that folder?

Comment: You don't. You need to get the list of filenames into the variable called `filenames` on your own. There's no concept of being able to read a folder in Javascript/HTML.

Comment: In fact come to think of it, if the filenames you're iterating through are the exact files you want to load in the image, why would a regular expression even be needed? Just put the filename itself into the `src` of the `img`.

Comment: Well there's a lot of different files that need to be displayed at different times based on what link the user clicks, and files are regularly generated so the number of them is not static.

Comment: What is your server-side environment? Somehow or other you will need to get the list of available files into your code. There is (more or less) nothing you can do in jQuery that will retrieve the list of files in a folder on your server.

Comment: I'm using visual studio, so I'd be doing the server-side scripting in asp.net (I come from a php background so I'm fairly new to asp.net).  Any functions that would be able to do this?

Comment: That's really a different question. I recommend reposting it with a new set of tags (asp.net).